# List of structures from unpack binary files fast

Tags: python, python-2.7

This structure is reading all file in loop:

```
def chunked_all(f):
    def read_item():
        return f.read(108)

    for data in iter(read_item, ''):
        info = struct.unpack_from("=HHBBBBBBHQHHIIIIHH32s32s", data)
        yield (info[9], info[11], info[15])

for i in chuncked_all(file):
    process_data(i)
```

I like to make it faster. Reading more of `108` bytes of data maintaining structure returned on `yield`.

**EDIT:**

Is possible to `struct.unpack_from` return list of `tuple` with `(info[9], info[11], info[15])`

```
def read_item():
    return f.read() # all data file

list_tuples = struct.unpack_from("=HHBBBBBBHQHHIIIIHH32s32s", read_item())
list_tuples
>>> [(1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3) ... ]
```

Comment: Have you tried *reading* more but only *yielding* 108 bytes at a time?

Comment: Yes. But need create other structure to return. `info` only have first 108 bytes.

Comment: I don't understand at all what that has to do with my question.

Comment: `f.read(108)` change to `f.read(108*10)` and the `info` only have first sequence of `108` bytes. Other bytes is lost on `for` loop.

Comment: That's why you yield them, 108 bytes at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def read_items(f):
  s = f.read(108*1000)
  for o in range(0, len(s), 108):
    yield buffer(s, o, 108)

for data in read_items(f):
   ...
```

Comment: It is 1% faster. I belive that the function  `unpack_from`  is the problem.

Comment: Why not use `unpack()`?

Comment: I use now. 2% faster.